# Is the content element used in Polymer 1.0?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, web-component

https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/local-dom#dom-distribution

In the above link under "Dom Distribution" it says:

> To support composition of an element's light DOM with its local DOM, Polymer supports the `<content>` element. ...

Just wondering if this is out of date?  Does Polymer 1.0 use slots as described here?

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/shadowdom/?hl=en#composition_slot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's definitely working in Polymer 1.0, even with Shadow DOM; I'm currently using it in my projects which use Polymer 1.6, but it may be outdated in Polymer 2.0 or a newer version.

@ebidel confirmed that they will add the slots to webcomponents.js, but currently nobody is assigned to it: https://github.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/issues/430

**UPDATE**

In the Polymer 1.7 they introduced the `<slot>` element for preparing to upgrade to 2.0 wich should be released soon. The 2.0 will not have the `<content>` element because they switching to the CustomElement v1 spec. I recommend that if you are plan to use `<content>` element then switch it to slot so in the future you will able to just upgrade the polymer library without heavy migrating.

The slot is working a bit different, the slot does not have a selector:

```
<dom-module id="my-element">
    <template>
        <slot name="content"></slot>
    </template>
    <script>
    Polymer({
        is: 'my-element'
    });
    </script>
</dom-module>

<my-element>
    <div slot="content">My Content</div>
</my-element>
```

Comment: You can use <slot></slot> without name attr for default content (but at the moment this broken, PR fix was merged to Polymer repo )